# Docker & nginx - Internal links not working

Tags: css, codeigniter, nginx, docker

I am using docker-compose to load a lemp stack and running a distribution of codeigniter that works find in a traditional stack but my assets are not loading when using docker.

I have the following directory structure on my PC

```
logs
  -nginx-access.log
  -nginx-error.log
nginx
  -default
public
  -application
  -assets
    -css
    -js
  -system
  -tests
  -index.php
  -etc etc etc etc
```

my nginx config file is as follows

```
    server {
    listen  80;

    # this path MUST be exactly as docker-compose.fpm.volumes,
    # even if it doesn't exists in this dock.
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.html;

    server_name 192.168.0.6;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
  nginx:
    image: tutum/nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    links:
        - phpfpm
    volumes:
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

        - ./logs/nginx-error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
        - ./logs/nginx-access.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log
phpfpm:
    image: php:fpm
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
        - ./public:/usr/share/nginx/html
mysql:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  restart: always
  links:
    - mysql
  ports:
    - 8183:80
  environment:
    MYSQL_USERNAME: admin
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
```

Any idea why the css file links are not working when using

```
<?php echo assets_url('css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>
```

The above command works fine in a LAMP stack on a virtual server.

Comment: Can you provide your docker-compose.yml?

Comment: I have added my docker-compose.yml file to the question

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you change `phpfpm:9000` to `phpfpm_1:9000`? It _shouldn't_ make a difference, but just in case.

Comment: Assuming that makes no difference, try execing onto the nginx container, install telnet and see if you can access phpfpm host on port 9000.

Comment: I may not have made it clear, but PHP is working fine. It is just the mapping to the assets folder that is not working as it should.

Comment: Ahh, right. Yeah, you need to add your assets volumes onto your nginx container where the vhost expects them. You're only forwarding PHP files onto PHP-FPM container which appear to be the only place with the assets. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks Jon, I added - ./public/assets:/usr/share/nginx/html/assets to my nginx volumes entry and it works fine. If you add as an answer and I will accept as the solution.